# How to get the headline title using org-entry-get

Tags: org-mode

**Q**:  How can `org-mode` be configured so that `(org-entry-get nil "title")` returns the headline title?

I have seen three variations of `org-entry-get` where the string argument `title` is in all lowercase, all uppercase, or initial caps.  The default `org-mode` configuration does not return anything in all three cases:

```
** Active [#A] 0 @ index. :lawlist:
  DEADLINE: <2016-12-31 Sat>
  :PROPERTIES:
  :Effort:
  :Hash: 8ae546845cebbc4d25ccdcf23eade44e
  :ToodledoFolder: TASKS
  :ToodledoGoal:
  :ToodledoID: 394554265
  :ToodledoLocation:
  :END:
```

---

```
(setq org-todo-keywords '((sequence
  "Active(a)"
  "Next Action(n)"
  "Canceled(c)"
  "Hold(h)"
  "Reference(r)"
  "Delegated(d)"
  "Waiting(w)"
  "Postponed(P)"
  "Someday(s)"
  "Planning(p)"
  "|"
  "None(N)")))
```

---

Here is a function I found that uses `org-get-heading` if `org-entry-get` fails:

```
(let ((title (if (org-entry-get nil "title")
                 (org-entry-get nil "title")
                 (org-get-heading t t))))
  (substring-no-properties title))
```

And, here is yet another method:  `(org-element-property :title (org-element-at-point))`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First to fix terminology, I think you are asking for the "heading" of the entry.  "Title" usually refers to the document title in `org-mode`.

With `org-mode` version `9.0.3` there is a function to retrieve elements of the heading, `org-heading-components', which returns a list whose 5th element is the title.  Thus the title my be retrieved by

```
(nth 4 (org-heading-components))
```

However, `org-mode` also maps the heading to a property.  Its name is not quite logical, but running `org-entry-properties` reveals that it is stored under `ITEM`.  Thus you are looking for

```
(org-entry-get nil "ITEM")
```

Comment: When the `org-todo-keywords` is defined, `(nth 4 (org-heading-components))` will return "**0 @ index.**".  However, `(org-entry-get nil "ITEM")` still returns `nil`.

Comment: "0 @ index." is correct. What were you hoping for? Also, you must be doing something wrong. (org-entry-get nil "ITEM") also returns "0 @ index." for me.

Comment: @John Kitchin -- thank you for confirming the expected behavior.  It turns out that the version of `org-mode` that ships with Emacs 25.1.1 is 8.2.10 and it does not support extracting `"ITEM"` with `org-entry-get`.  The most recent version of `org-mode` that can be installed separately is 9.0.3 and it does indeed support this feature.  I have posted an alternative answer explaining the issue, but will accept the answer by @Andrew Swann because most people will opt to simply upgrade to the latest version of `org-mode`.

Answer (score 2):

The current stable version of Emacs as of 01/08/2017 is 25.1.1, which was released on or about 09/20/2016.  The version of `org-mode` that ships with the aforementioned version of Emacs is 8.2.10.  The current stable of release of `org-mode` as of 01/08/2017 is 9.0.3.

As to `org-mode` version 8.2.10, `"ITEM"` is *not* a member of `org-special-properties` by default.  As to `org-mode` version 8.2.10, the function `org-entry-properties` does *not* have a subsection specifically allocated to extracting the `"ITEM"`.  Here is what the *missing* snippet would look like if someone wanted to add this feature -- the logical place to plug this snippet in would be between the section dealing with `"PRIORITY"` and the section dealing with `"FILE"`:

```lisp
(when (or (not specific) (string= specific "ITEM"))
  (let ((case-fold-search nil))
    (when (looking-at org-complex-heading-regexp)
      (push (cons "ITEM"
                  (let ((title (match-string-no-properties 4)))
                    (if (org-string-nw-p title)
                      (org-remove-tabs title)
                      "")))
            props))))
```

As to `org-mode` version 9.0.3, `"ITEM"` **is** a member of `org-special-properties` by default.  As to `org-mode` version 9.0.3, the function `org-entry-properties` already has a dedication section to deal with `"ITEM"` -- said function has also evolved in other aspects since 8.2.10 (e.g., `catch 'exit` and `throw exit ...`).

Since most people will likely upgrade to the most recent version of `org-mode`, @lawlist will accept the answer of @Andrew Swann.